# Sorting Custom Object Columns

Tags: powershell

Lately, I've been playing around with custom objects in PowerShell. I'm getting the hang of it except I don't understand why PowerShell displays my objects in a seemingly random order. For example

```
$i = 0; $a = @()
$Disks = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk

ForEach($Disk in $Disks){

    $props = @{'Disk' = $Disks.DeviceID[$i];
    'Size GB' = "{0:F1}" -f ($Disks.size[$i] / 1GB)}
    $a += New-Object psobject -Property $props
    $i++

}

$a
```

Output is shown as 'Size GB' then 'Disk'. I want 'Disk' then 'Size GB'. Example 2:

```
$Computers = 'Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3'
$ComputerInfo = 1..$Computers.Length
$props = @{NAME = ""; MAC_ADDR = ""; IP_ADDR = "" }
$Cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Credentials"
$i=0

#Gather requested information for each $computer in $computers
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {

    Write-Host "Gathering information on $computer..."
    $ComputerInfo[$i] = New-Object psobject -property $props

    Try {
        $wmiquery = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computer $Computer -filter "IPEnabled='True'" -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $ComputerInfo[$i].NAME = $computer
        $ComputerInfo[$i].MAC_ADDR = $wmiquery.MACAddress
         $ComputerInfo[$i].IP_ADDR = $wmiquery.IPAddress[0]
    } Catch {
         Write-Host "Unable to query: $computer"
    }

    $i++
}

#Display information
$ComputerInfo
```

Output is shown as 'MAC_ADDR' then 'IP_ADDR' then 'NAME'. I want 'NAME' then 'MAC_ADDR' then 'IP_ADDR'.

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of creating custom objects that you are making use of in the above script do not have a method to sort them. To have the results returned in a predefined order you have to change the way the custom object is made.

```
$Disks = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk

$arr = @()
$Disks | ForEach-Object{
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Disk -Value $_.DeviceID
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Size GB" -Value $([math]::truncate($_.Size / 1GB))
    $arr += $obj
}

Write-Output $arr
```

The above will always return the object properties in the order they are added, in this case Disk then Size GB.

More on working with custom object can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff730946.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The entries in your `$props` hashtable are not necessarily stored in the order you define them:

```
PS C:\> $Props = @{ Disk=123; Size=10240 }
PS C:\> $Props

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Size                           10240
Disk                           123
```

To maintain the order, use the `[ordered]` type accelerator to create an [ordered dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
PS C:\> $Props = [ordered]@{ Disk=123; Size=10240 }
PS C:\> New-Object psobject -Property $Props

Disk  Size
----  ----
 123 10240
```

Works in PowerShell 3.0 or newer